# React native - Webview cannot call js file on next page transition

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

I'm having a bit of a bug: I'm embedding the webview into the app and pulling the js to do some more functions on the gpt chat, I'll embed the chatgpt page into the webview and everything is fine and the next thing I'll do is Call a js file to create some utilities to support the use of gpt chat.

However, when I first enter the app, everything looks fine, the gpt chat page is still embedded and the js file is still called and the functions are still there, however when I click to go to the login page or any other page, the file appears. js doesn't work (maybe it's not being called, because I can't debug the webview on the computer... but the log is still running). Hopefully someone can tell me the problem, below is my code...

**This is the code calling the js file:**

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Text, View, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const webViewRef = useRef(null);
  const [isScriptInjected, setIsScriptInjected] = useState(false);

  const customScript = `
    async function loadScript() {
      const scriptElement = document.createElement("script");
      scriptElement.setAttribute("src", 'https://bck.com/fc.js');
      scriptElement.setAttribute("loadScript", "BCK");
      scriptElement.setAttribute("type", "module");
      scriptElement.onload = () => { };
      scriptElement.onerror = error => { };
      document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);
  }
  loadScript()
  `;

  const onNavigationStateChange = (navState) => {
    const { url } = navState;
    console.log(navState)
    console.log(webViewRef.current)
    console.log(customScript)
    webViewRef.current.injectJavaScript(customScript);
    if (webViewRef.current) {
    }
  };
```

**Next is the webview embed code as usual:**

```js
 const onLoadStart = () => {
    setLoading(true);
  };

  const onLoadEnd = () => {
    setLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.main}>
        {loading && <View style={styles.loadingOverlay}><Text>Loading...</Text></View>}
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.web}>
          <WebView
            ref={webViewRef}
            source={{ uri: 'https://chat.openai.com/' }}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            onNavigationStateChange={onNavigationStateChange}
            onLoadStart={onLoadStart}
            onLoadEnd={onLoadEnd}
            javaScriptEnabled={true}
            domStorageEnabled={true}
            startInLoadingState={true}
            scalesPageToFit={true}
            originWhitelist={['*']}
          />
        </SafeAreaView>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

Hope there will be some solution for me, thanks very much everyone ^^